# I would like to aggregate all values for a specific month in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I would to create a table which takes values from an existing table.
The existing table has the following columns:

```
NAME VARCHAR2(255 BYTE) , 
TYPE VARCHAR2(255 BYTE) , 
DT_CHECKPOINT VARCHAR2(255 BYTE),  
STATUS VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)
```

And I have rows like this:

```
record 1: U83   PC/BC   21/10/2023  OK
record 2: U83   PC/BC   22/10/2023  KO
record 3: FR    DH      22-OTT-23   KO
record 4: FR    DH      25-OTT-23   KO
```

I want to create a new table which count the KO values and OK values during the month like this:

```
record 1: U83      PC/BC    OTT-23  1  1
record 2: FR        DH      OTT-23  0  2
```

How can be to create this table? I know that it's incorrect that DT_CHECKPOINT is a VARCHAR2 but I can't change it

Comment: So what have you tried and what specific issue are you facing?

Comment: In deed, what does `22-OTT-23` mean? 22nd October 2023 or 23rd October 2022 or even 22nd October 1923? or 23rd October 1922?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what is the logic behind partial date string beeing 'OTT-23' in both rows. So, excluding that you can use conditional aggregation with grouping by first 2 columns:

```sql
WITH    --  S a m p l e   D a t a :
    tbl ( A_NAME, A_TYPE, DT_CHECKPOINT, STATUS ) AS
        ( Select 'U83', 'PC/BC', '21/10/2023', 'OK' From Dual Union All
          Select 'U83', 'PC/BC', '22/10/2023', 'KO' From Dual Union All
          Select 'FR',  'DH',    '22-OTT-23',  'KO' From Dual Union All
          Select 'FR',  'DH',    '25-OTT-23',  'KO' From Dual 
        )
```

```sql
--  M a i n    S Q L :
Select  A_NAME, A_TYPE,         
        Count(Case When STATUS = 'KO' Then 1 End) "KO_COUNT",
        Count(Case When STATUS = 'OK' Then 1 End) "OK_COUNT"
From    tbl
Group By A_NAME, A_TYPE
Order By A_NAME Desc
```

```sql
/*    R e s u l t :
A_NAME A_TYPE   KO_COUNT   OK_COUNT
------ ------ ---------- ----------
U83    PC/BC           1          1
FR     DH              2          0   */
```

If you explain why the date part should be like asked maybe someone could help. One of the options is to take Max() of partial string but the result is not as asked for.

```sql
Select  A_NAME, A_TYPE,     
        Max(SubStr(DT_CHECKPOINT, 4)) "DT_CHECK",
        Count(Case When STATUS = 'KO' Then 1 End) "KO_COUNT",
        Count(Case When STATUS = 'OK' Then 1 End) "OK_COUNT"
From    tbl
Group By A_NAME, A_TYPE
Order By A_NAME Desc

/*    R e s u l t :
A_NAME A_TYPE DT_CHECK   KO_COUNT   OK_COUNT
------ ------ -------- ---------- ----------
U83    PC/BC  10/2023           1          1
FR     DH     OTT-23            2          0 */
```

Comment: Yes, I need to create a table that contains the information for the entire most recent month for a certain FLOW_NAME. In this case I need to group for the most recent month (e.g. December) for each FLOW_NAME (in this case it would be the NAME column) how many KO and how many OK values there are. For example, if I have flow_name information from the 30 days of December in my table, I have to group all this information into another table that contains a single record representing the month of December

Comment: @MarioS If your dates are of VarChar2 type and uncontrolably  populated like in the question you can forget anything concerning dates (months or anything else). Without that mess the counting of KOs And OKs is in the first code.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer number 2.**
Beside the bad practice with dates in columns of VarChar2 datatype, under some conditions, maybe something could be done with all this mess. From your data provided could be that at least one thing with your dates could be consistent. It looks like the order of date parts is always day, month, year. If that is true (or you can make it true) and if you can get ridd of possible typos (like SETT instead of SET for September) there is something that could be done with different separators or lengths of particular date parts. On the other hand, you should know distinct delimiters used in your VarChar2 data.
I changed a bit your sample data to have more diversities.

```sql
WITH    --  C h a n g e d   S a m p l e   D a t a :
    tbl ( A_NAME, A_TYPE, DT_CHECKPOINT, STATUS ) AS
        ( Select 'U83', 'PC/BC', '21.10.2023', 'OK' From Dual Union All
          Select 'U83', 'PC/BC', '22/10/2023', 'KO' From Dual Union All
          Select 'FR',  'DH',    '22-10-23',  'KO' From Dual Union All
          Select 'FR',  'DH',    '25-OTT-23',  'KO' From Dual 
        ),
```

1. create cte with numbers and distinct delimiters (here: blank, dot, minus, slash) and insert your own delimiter for both. Something that is not in your data

```sql
    format_elements AS
        ( Select '~0~1~2~3~4~5~6~7~8~9~' "NUMS", '~ ~.~-~/~' "DELIMS"
          From Dual 
        ),
```

2. create cte deconstructing each date with some properties for every character

```sql
    dt_grid AS
        ( Select  Distinct
                      TRIM(t.DT_CHECKPOINT) "DT", 
                      LEVEL "POSITION", 
                      Length(TRIM(t.DT_CHECKPOINT)) "LEN", 
                      SubStr(TRIM(t.DT_CHECKPOINT), LEVEL, 1) "A_CHAR",
                      Case  When InStr(fe.NUMS, '~' || SubStr(TRIM(t.DT_CHECKPOINT), LEVEL, 1) || '~') > 0
                            Then 'NUM'
                            When InStr(fe.DELIMS, '~' || SubStr(TRIM(t.DT_CHECKPOINT), LEVEL, 1) || '~') > 0
                            Then 'DELIM'
                      Else  'NONE'
                      End "NUM_DELIM"
          From        tbl t
          Inner Join  format_elements fe ON(1=1)
          Connect By  LEVEL <= Length(TRIM(DT_CHECKPOINT))
          Order By    TRIM(DT_CHECKPOINT), LEVEL
        ),
```

```sql
/*  d t _ g r i d    r e s u l t :
DT           POSITION        LEN A NUM_DELIM
---------- ---------- ---------- - ---------
21.10.2023          1         10 2 NUM  
21.10.2023          2         10 1 NUM  
21.10.2023          3         10 . DELIM
21.10.2023          4         10 1 NUM  
21.10.2023          5         10 0 NUM  
21.10.2023          6         10 . DELIM
21.10.2023          7         10 2 NUM  
21.10.2023          8         10 0 NUM  
21.10.2023          9         10 2 NUM  
21.10.2023         10         10 3 NUM 
...
...
...
25-OTT-23           1          9 2 NUM  
25-OTT-23           2          9 5 NUM  
25-OTT-23           3          9 - DELIM
25-OTT-23           4          9 O NONE 
25-OTT-23           5          9 T NONE 
25-OTT-23           6          9 T NONE 
25-OTT-23           7          9 - DELIM
25-OTT-23           8          9 2 NUM  
25-OTT-23           9          9 3 NUM  */
```

3. create cte generating months as '01' ... '12' plus 'GEN' ... 'DIC' ('JAN' .. 'DEC')

```sql
    month_conversion AS
        ( Select  LPAD(LEVEL, 2, '0') "MONTH_ID_1", 
                  To_Char(To_Date('2023-' || LPAD(LEVEL, 2, '0') || '-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'MON')  "MONTH_ID_2"
          From    Dual 
          Connect By LEVEL <= 12 Order By LEVEL
        ),
```

4. create last cte combining all above to get back the date rows from previous decostruction

```sql
    dates AS
        ( SELECT    g.*, m.MONTH_ID_2 || '-' || SubStr(g.DT_CHECKPOINT, -2) "MONTH_CHECKPOINT"
          FROM    ( SELECT    DT "DT_CHECKPOINT", 
                              Max(Case When DELIM_NO = 1 Then DT_PART End) "DT_PART_1",
                              Max(Case When DELIM_NO = 2 Then SubStr(DT_PART, InStr(DT_PART, A_CHAR) + 1) End) "DT_PART_2", 
                              SubStr(DT, -2) "DT_PART_3"
                    FROM    (Select     DT, POSITION, LEN, A_CHAR, NUM_DELIM, 
                                        Case  When NUM_DELIM = 'DELIM' 
                                              Then Count(1) Over(Partition By DT, A_CHAR Order By POSITION Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) 
                                        End "DELIM_NO", 
                                        
                                        CASE WHEN NUM_DELIM = 'DELIM' 
                                              THEN SubStr(DT, 1, POSITION - 1)
                                        END "DT_PART"
                             From       dt_grid
                             Order By   DT, POSITION
                            ) 
                    
                    GROUP BY DT
                    ORDER BY DT
                  ) g 
          LEFT JOIN month_conversion m ON(m.MONTH_ID_1 = g.DT_PART_2 Or m.MONTH_ID_2 = g.DT_PART_2)
        )
```

```sql
/*      d a t e s    r e s u l t :
DT_CHECKPOINT DT_PART_1   DT_PART_2    DT_PART_3 MONTH_CHECKPOINT
------------- ----------- ----------- ---------- -----------------
21.10.2023    21          10          23         OTT-23         
22/10/2023    22          10          23         OTT-23         
22-10-23      22          10          23         OTT-23         
25-OTT-23     25          OTT         23         OTT-23             */
```

5. Finalize it in a way from my first answer but now joined with unified string for month fetched from your VarChar2 dates...

```sql
--  M a i n    S Q L :
Select  t.A_NAME, t.A_TYPE, d.MONTH_CHECKPOINT,       
        Count(Case When t.STATUS = 'KO' Then 1 End) "KO_COUNT",
        Count(Case When t.STATUS = 'OK' Then 1 End) "OK_COUNT"
From    tbl t
Left Join dates d ON(d.DT_CHECKPOINT = t.DT_CHECKPOINT)
Group By t.A_NAME, t.A_TYPE, d.MONTH_CHECKPOINT
Order By t.A_NAME Desc
/*
A_NAME A_TYPE MONTH_CHECKPOINT        KO_COUNT   OK_COUNT
----- ------- --------------------- ---------- ----------
U83   PC/BC   OTT-23                         1          1
FR    DH      OTT-23                         2          0   */
```

NOTE: I changed NLS_LANGUAGE to ITALIAN to match sample data. This works under stated conditions. Any anomaly in the data that are not present in this sample data requires intervention in this code to handle that specific anomaly. I don't know your data and can't know what else is there but this (at least) could be a guidance how to analyze and, if possible, normalize "the mess"